# BASIC SQL - Case expression - Modifying "Then 1 Else 0" To return count of rows where case statement is true

Tags: sql, count, case

I am a sales professional interested in honing my SQL skills further. Stackoverflow has been a great resource for me thus far!

**Goal:**

I want to get a distinct count of all our customers by DMA (aka Metro U.S. Area) where the case expression below is true.

**PROBLEM**

Right now, when I execute the query, the resulting count for the "current month -1" column (which should return the count of all customers who match the case statement) is just returning a 1. I would like for this to return the count of o.intorgnodeID (customer IDS) in which the case expression was true (57 customers).

In other words, I suspect that the "then 1" part of the case statement is what is causing me issues. But I am not sure how to modify the "1' to count just the results of the original case statement

```
SELECT
    o.strDMANode --- AKA Metro Market
    ,case when(sum(case when (year(getdate()) - 1) * 12 + month(getdate()) - ((year(sbi.dtmdelivered) - 1) * 12 + month(sbi.dtmdelivered))  = 24 then 1 else 0 end)) >0 then 1 else 0 end as 'Current Month - 1' --- this is the output column that I hope to have return a value of '57'. Currently is returning a '1'
FROM sqlfact.dbo.uvwreport as sbi
    JOIN [sqlDim].[dbo].[uvwdimOrgNodeType1] o ON [sbi].[intDimOrgNodeID] = [o].[intDimOrgNodeID]
    JOIN [sqlDim].[dbo].[uvwdimProductType1] as "z" ON [sbi].[intDimProductPrimaryID] = [z].[intDimProductID]
WHERE 
    ([sbi].[intstatusid] = 5 OR sbi.intsubstatusid = 43) --- Includes only delivered reports
    and [sbi].[mnyDollarcost] > 0 --- NO $0 reports
    and [o].[bitCurrent] = 1 --- Excludes all historical versions of OrgNode, which were duplicates
    and [o].[strSalesRegionNodeGroup]  = 'Construction' 
GROUP BY [o].[strDMANode]
ORDER BY [o].[strDMANode] asc
```

*CURRENT RESULTS:*

```
strDMANode               Result
ABILENE-SWEETWATER DMA 1
```

DESIRED RESULTS:

```
strDMANode Column        Result
ABILENE-SWEETWATER DMA   57
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `case` as an argument to `sum()`:

```
sum(case when(case when (year(getdate()) - 1) * 12 + month(getdate()) - ((year(sbi.dtmdelivered) - 1) * 12 + month(sbi.dtmdelivered))  = 24 then 1 else 0 end)) >0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Current Month - 1'
```

Comment: Okay, so when I attempt to use that string of code, I get an error telling me: ```Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.```